# Mi JavaScript Se buggea

Tags: javascript

Les quería preguntar por cual motivo el codigo JavaScript se buggea al ejecutar el evento, pero si lo hago desde consola funciona.
Al momento en el cual se ejecuta el evento "Change" la web se queda buggeada y no responde. Agradezco mucho su ayuda ante el problema.

```js
function EuclidesMCD(a, b) {
    var iaux; //auxiliar
    a = Math.abs(a); //tomamos valor absoluto
    b = Math.abs(b);
    var i1 = Math.max(a, b); //i1 = el más grande
    var i2 = Math.min(a, b); //i2 = el más pequeño
  
    do {
      iaux = i2; //guardar divisor
      i2 = i1 % i2; //resto pasa a divisor
      i1 = iaux; //divisor pasa a dividendo
    } while (i2 !== 0);
     //ultimo resto no nulo
    document.getElementById("denominadorOutput").innerHTML = b/i1 
   document.getElementById("numeradorOutput").innerHTML = a/i1
}

var numeradorInput = document.getElementById("numeradorInput").value
var denominadorInput =  document.getElementById("denominadorInput").value

document.getElementById("numeradorInput").addEventListener("keyup", ()=>
EuclidesMCD(numeradorInput, denominadorInput))

document.getElementById("denominadorInput").addEventListener("change", ()=>
EuclidesMCD(numeradorInput, denominadorInput))
```

```css
#content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 50vh;
    border: groove;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.fracciones{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15vh;
}

hr{
    width: 10vw;
}

input{
    text-align: center;
    width: 3vw;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}


.outputBox{
    text-align: center;
}

.inputBox{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Styles.css">
    <title>Fracciones irreducibles</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Calculadora de fracciones irreducibles</h1>
        <div class="fracciones">
            <div class="inputBox">
                <input type="number" name="numeradorInput" id="numeradorInput">
                <hr>
                <input type="number" name="denominadorInput" id="denominadorInput">
            </div>
            <h3>=</h3>
            <div class="outputBox">
                <span id="numeradorOutput"></span>
                <hr>
                <span id="denominadorOutput"></span>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
    <script src="JS/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor sobre el error obtenido?

Comment: Ahi agregué información :)

Comment: @Vencho el sitio cuenta con su propio fiddle, por favor edita tu pregunta y coloca el código en el. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenias un error en el do while, por alguna razon no tomaba los valores de los input y se quedaba en un ciclo indefinido.

Aqui mejore un poco tu code y funciona perfecto.

```js
function reduce(numerator,denominator){
    var gcd = function gcd(a,b){
        return b ? gcd(b, a%b) : a;
    };
    gcd = gcd(numerator,denominator);
    return [numerator/gcd, denominator/gcd];
}

function EuclidesMCD(a, b) {

    numeradorInput = document.getElementById("numeradorInput").value
    denominadorInput = document.getElementById("denominadorInput").value

    var reducidos = reduce(numeradorInput,denominadorInput);
    console.log(reducidos)

    document.getElementById("denominadorOutput").innerHTML = reducidos[1]
    document.getElementById("numeradorOutput").innerHTML = reducidos[0]
}

var numeradorInput = document.getElementById("numeradorInput").value
var denominadorInput = document.getElementById("denominadorInput").value

document.getElementById("numeradorInput").addEventListener("keyup", () =>
    EuclidesMCD(numeradorInput, denominadorInput))

document.getElementById("denominadorInput").addEventListener("change", () =>
    EuclidesMCD(numeradorInput, denominadorInput))
```

```css
#content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 50vh;
    border: groove;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.fracciones {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15vh;
}

hr {
    width: 10vw;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    width: 3vw;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}


.outputBox {
    text-align: center;
}

.inputBox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        <title>Fracciones irreducibles</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Calculadora de fracciones irreducibles</h1>
            <div class="fracciones">
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="number" name="numeradorInput" id="numeradorInput">
                    <hr>
                    <input type="number" name="denominadorInput" id="denominadorInput">
                </div>
                <h3>=</h3>
                <div class="outputBox">
                    <span id="numeradorOutput"></span>
                    <hr>
                    <span id="denominadorOutput"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora funciona de maravilla!